# Tesseract - digit regonition with many errors

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

I want to be able to recognize digits from images. So I have been playing around with tesseract and python. I looked into how to prepare the image and tried running tesseract on it and I must say I am pretty disappointed by how badly my digits are recognized. I have tried to prepare my images with OpenCV and thought I did a pretty good job (see examples below) but tesseract has a lot of errors when trying to identify my images. Am I expecting too much here? But when I look at these example images I think that tesseract should easily be able to identify these digits without any problems. I am wondering if the accuracy is not there yet or if somehow my configuration is not optimal. Any help or direction would be gladly appreciated.

Things I tried to improve the digit recognition: (nothing seemed to improved the results significantly)

- limit characters: `config = "--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789"`
- Upscale images
- add a white border around the image to give the letters more space, as I have read that this improves the recognition process
- Threshold image to only have black and white pixels

Examples:

**Image 1:**

Tesseract recognized: 72
[image]

**Image 2:**

Tesseract recognized: 0
[image]

EDIT:
**Image 3:**

https://ibb.co/1qVtRYL

Tesseract recognized: 1723

Comment: Have you tried textract? https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract

Comment: I think textract doesn't work with images or am I wrong? I want to be able to recognize these digits from images.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going wrong for you. I downloaded those images and tesseract interprets them just fine for me. What version of tesseract are you using (I'm using 5.0)?

781429

209441

```py
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# set path
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Users\\ichu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe';

# load images
first = cv2.imread("first_text.png");
second = cv2.imread("second_text.png");
images = [first, second];

# convert to pillow
pimgs = [];
for img in images:
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    pimgs.append(Image.fromarray(rgb));

# do text
for img in pimgs:
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789');
    print(text[:-2]); # drops newline + end char
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes I am also using version 5. I downloaded both images and to my suprise they both worked. I am not sure why. My guess is that maybe the screenshot i took from these images changes the resolution therefore changed the behaviour of tesseract. I however have added a third image which seems to fail even when i test it as a seperate image with your script.

Comment: can you add the image to your question?

Comment: Yeah sorry, the image was somehow to large for stackoverflow so i had to upload it somewhere else

Comment: huh, tesseract is impressively awful at recognizing ones. I almost wonder if it'd be worth it to convert to text without the numbers restriction and just substitute the characters it finds with numbers. (It recognizes the third image as WS 723).

Comment: Exactly! I am quite lost what to do here. Replacing W and S with 1 seems quite random and I think I would have problems with 5 getting recognized as S (because then i would need to replace S with 5 and not 1). Do you have any suggestions what i could do here? Is tesseract the way to go? I thought it would be quite simple if i prepared the image well enough but apparently not. Would a different approach be better? Maybe template matching? Seems quite tedious but maybe there would be consitent results?

Comment: you can do template matching if you suspect your numbers will mostly look the same. If you go that route, I'd suggest keeping multiple examples of each digit in separate folders so that you have a few chances to detect each character.

Comment: Alright, I will look into that, thank you for your answers